# Meteor returning method not found error

Tags: javascript, meteor

```
Drug = new Mongo.Collection('drugData');
if(Meteor.isClient)
{
    Template.drugs.events(
        {
            'submit .new-drug':function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = event.target.name.value;
                var type = event.target.type.value;
                var rating = Number(event.target.Rating.value);

                Meteor.call('addDrug',name,type,rating);

                event.target.name.value="";
                event.target.type.value="";
                event.target.Rating.value="";
            }
        });

    Template.drugs.helpers(
        {
            'druglist':function()
            {
                return Drug.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}});
            }
        }
    );
}
if(Meteor.isServer)
{
  Meteor.publish('druglist',function()
      {
         return Drug.find(); 
      });   
}

Meteor.methods(
    {
        addDrug:function(name,type,rating)
        {               
                Drug.insert(
                    {
                        name:name,
                        type:type,
                        rating:rating,
                        createdAt:new Date()
                    });             
        }
    }
);
```

//////my router///////

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'layout'
});
Router.map(function()
    {
        this.route('login',{path:'/'});
        this.route('claims',{path:'/claims'});
        this.route('clients',{path:'/clients'});
        this.route('employees',{path:'/employees'});
    });

    Router.route('/drugs',
        {
            name:'drugs',
            template:'drugs',
            data: function()
            {
                Meteor.subscribe('druglist');
            }
        });
```

I'm new to meteor and i am currently learning routing, i am having a problem displaying my data when using routing with publish and subscribe. When i run the code with autopublish and insecure and don't use publish and subscribe my data shows on my pages, but when i remove autopublish and insecure and use publish and subscribe i get the error 'method "addDrug" not found:404'.

This is my template code

```
<template name="drugs">
    <h3>this is the drugs page</h3>
    <form class= "new-drug">
        <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Drug name">
        <input name="type" type="text" placeholder="Drug Classification">
        <input name="Rating" type="text" placeholder="Drug Rating">
        <button type="submit">Add Drug<span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>
    </form>
    <div>
        <ol>
            {{#each druglist}}
            <li>{{name}}--{{type}}--{{rating}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ol>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data option you are using in the route is the equivalent of a template helper function, and can not be used for subscribing to a collection. 
Subscribing is done with the waitOn or subscriptions option.

```
Router.route('/drugs',
{
    name:'drugs',
    template:'drugs',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('druglist');
    },
    data: function() {
        return { druglist: Drug.find({},{sort:{createdAt:-1}}) };
    }
});
```

With this code you wouldn't need the helper anymore.

Comment: The waitOn and subscriptions options are almost identical, except that the subscriptions option is only used for data subscription.

Comment: So i replaced my existing routing code with yours and took out the helper function from my javascript code and the page just loads and instead of  showing my form like it did before all i get is a page showing loading. it seems to be stuck on the waitOn function.

Comment: Are you still publishing the collection? I'm only able to regenerate the Loading.. status you have when I remove the publish function. Can you show me the relevant template code?

Comment: That all seems right. It works fine here. Did you rerun: meteor remove autopublish ? You could also try to replace "waitOn" with "subscriptions". Do you get any errors in your console?